# Summarize parameters in this simple jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I need both variables (mySwipe1, mySwipe2), but I don’t want to repeat the parameters in .photoSwipe({...})

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a").photoSwipe({ 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    });         
    var mySwipe2 = $("#Div2 a").photoSwipe({ 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    });

});
</script>
```

**Further information:**
I’m a designer. This is part of a portfolio gallery for my website. If I summarize the div elements in one variable `var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a, #Div2 a").photoSwipe({...` the two intended galleries become one. I need multiple galleries.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If this is real code, I would highly recommend not using `Div1` and `Div2` as IDs... they aren't descriptive at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
var opts = { 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    };
var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a").photoSwipe(opts); 
var mySwipe2 = $("#Div2 a").photoSwipe(opts);
```

If you want to keep some properties of the first swipe and override some in the second you can use

```
var firstSwipe = {
 captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
            captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
            doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
            imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
            loop: false,
            preventSlideshow: true
},
secondSwipe = $.extend(firstSwipe, {
  preventSlideshow: false // some override
});
var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a").photoSwipe(firstSwipe); 
var mySwipe2 = $("#Div2 a").photoSwipe(secondSwipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an object with your parameters :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mySettings = { 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    };

    var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a").photoSwipe(mySettings);         
    var mySwipe2 = $("#Div2 a").photoSwipe(mySettings);

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single config object that you pass to both initializations:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var config = { 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    };

    var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a").photoSwipe(config);         
    var mySwipe2 = $("#Div2 a").photoSwipe(config);

});
```

OR you could initialize both `photoSwipes` at once, if the plugin supports that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mySwipe1 = $("#Div1 a, #Div2 a").photoSwipe({ 
        captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, 
        captionAndToolbarFlipPosition: true,
        doubleTapZoomLevel: 2,
        imageScaleMethod:  "fitNoUpscale",
        loop: false,
        preventSlideshow: true
    });
});
```